# How convert integer matrix to specific String in matlab

Tags: matlab

For example, I have this Matrix:

```
a=[100,20,3,2000]
```

I want to save every integer in 4 places in string. However the last integer matrix will be

```
s='0100002000032000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = ''
for i = 1:size(a, 2)
    s = [s sprintf('%04d', a(i))]
end
```

Or, even simpler, do:

```
s = num2str(a, '%04d')
```

Comment: @HasanEdrees The best way to thank someone for giving you a helpful answer on Stack Overflow is to **accept** their answer. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)